# Elevated voltage after a filtering capacitor

Tags: bridge-rectifier

When the secondary coil of a power transformer provides 44V to each side of a bridge rectifier relative to the ground, i.e. 88V total, and I measure +53V and -63V after the rectifier on the filtering electrolytic capacitors, and those voltages have no visible pulsations, what can explain the elevated -63V?

The schematics calls for +-51V, so +53V is slightly over, but not a major concern, while -63V is considerable overvoltage.

Pretty much as in this diagram:

[image]

The rectifier in question is RBV-602 and the caps are 10,000uF 71V.

I would expect -63V pulses if there was no cap, but why with a cap?

Comment: With no load.. what do you think the caps will charge up to?

Comment: The schematic shows no ground connection between centre tap and 0V. If that reflects reality, no wonder you're seeing an imbalance.

Comment: This is becoming ridiculous, I am regretting joining this SO. Thanks everyone!

Comment: You're the one who provided inaccurate/incomplete information. Don't be complaining about the responses you got in return. Ask a bad question, get a bad answer. It's as simple as that. All of the comments and answers you received were perfectly legit, asking for more information and providing some in return based on what was provided.

Comment: " no visible pulsations" - Do you mean no pulsations on your DC meter, no visible flickering on an LED, or no AC component visible on a scope trace?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast My question exactly

Comment: Diagram says 24V and text says 44V. assuming RMS, Vp of 44 is 62 V no load. Yet load is not stated. With 10mF caps I expect load power is small for low ripple. But what is power source rating and line f?  and what is load ?  How was V measured? Too many unknowns in this question deserves downgrading. Pls include answers in your question to restore those who may have down-voted. When I started power audio designs with these voltages back in the late '60's we only used 50mF to 100mF computer grade caps.  You may want to consider SMPS designs. This is an "old school" unregulated supply.

Answer (score 1):

> I would expect -63V pulses if there was no cap, but why with a cap?

If you expect 63V pulses from the rectifier, and there is no load and consequent discharge path for the capacitors, the capacitors will continue to charge up to whatever peak voltage your transformer is generating minus a bit for the diode drops.

Why the value is different on either side... I have no idea. However, perhaps you do have more load on one side than the other.

Answer (score 0):

AC voltage is measured in RMS. When you rectify it you can no longer measure it this way, as it is now DC, which is equivalent to the peak voltage of the AC supply. Therefore, to convert RMS to peak (or DC) you need to multiply the supply by 1.414. I would expect `44V * 1.414 = 62.2` volts DC during normal use.

The lower voltage (51 volts) could very well be caused by imperfect windings on the transformer. They are rarely accurate. You really need some form of regulation after the smoothing capacitors in order to get your required output voltage.

Comment: If there was an "imperfect wiring" on the transformer, there would be no perfectly equal 44V AC on each coil.

Comment: Are you measuring exactly 44VAC on both sides of the winding? You failed to mention that in your post

Comment: It's right in the first line.

Comment: The way it's worded it sounds like that's the *expected* voltage on each winding. You didn't make it clear that you were actually *measuring* that voltage. Anyway, incomplete or improper filtering (i.e. undersized caps) could also explain the discrepancy

Comment: "Provides" means that's the actual measurement. If one of the caps lost capacitance, there would be pulsations which I would have noticed, but it's perfectly filtered.

Comment: Not necessarily, it is also often used to describe a hypothetical or ideal description. I suggest you edit your question to clarify. If you don't want unclear answers, don't ask an unclear question. Make sure all of the details are included and are correct, and make sure all of the text is as clear as possible

Comment: How do you know it's perfectly filtered? Are you monitoring the output on an oscilloscope? Otherwise you may *not* notice the ripple

Comment: And along with what @Trevor suggested, do you have a load connected?

Comment: Are you making these measurements with a scope or with a DVM.  Most DVMs do not have a true RMS converter, so any input or transformer waveform distortion will change the measurement.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the picture the voltage peaks is what a capacitor will charge to without load on the output.

[image]